# Error: IDL doesnt exist. | Rust | Solana | Anchor

Tags: ubuntu, rust, anchor, solana, idl

I tried to build my project `anchor build` but I got

```
$ Error: IDL doesn't exist
```

`target/idl/` and `target/types/` were generated but they were empty.
Then I tried `anchor clean` , `anchor build`. The same.

Then I tried anchor `idl init -f <filepath> <program id>`

```
$ Error: Is a directory (os error 21)
```

Then I finally tried `anchor build -v`

```
Using image "backpackapp/build:v0.29.0"
Run docker image
Error during Docker build: Docker build failed: No such file or directory (os error 2)
Error: Docker build failed: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I also tried:

- change `idl = true` in `Anchor.toml`
- delete `no-idl = []` string in `Cargo.toml`

I'm on Ubuntu

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by reinstalling `anchor-cli`:

```bash
cargo uninstall anchor-cli
cargo install anchor-cli --version 0.27.0
```